# write binary files using hadoop filesystem org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

Tags: hadoop, binary, hdfs, nio

I used to generate binary file using a MappedByteBuffer and FileChannel like that:

```
  final Path fullPath = ..
  final File parent = fullPath.toFile();
  FileChannel out=null;
  out = new RandomAccessFile(new File(parent, "myFileName"), "rw").getChannel();
  MappedByteBuffer buffer=null;
  buffer = out.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, size);
  buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
  buffer.putInt(12);
  buffer.putFloat(25);
  buffer.putFloat(32);
```

I tried to do generate the same binary file using hadoop api like this:

```
  FileSystem hadoopFileSys= hadoopDataSource.getFileSystem();

   FSDataOutputStream outputStream=null;
   outputStream = hadoopFileSys.create(hadoopPath);
   outputStream.writeInt(12);
   outputStream.writeFloat(25);
   outputStream.writeFloat(32);
```

**My problem is that the generated file using hadoop api is not identique to the file generated using nio api.**

I need that the two genrated files be the same because they will parsed by the same tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop FS uses big endian. So you really need to use:

```
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
```

nio:

```
00 00 00 0C 41 C8 00 00 42 00 00 00
```

hadoop:

```
00 00 00 0C 41 C8 00 00 42 00 00 00
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, there is a way to make hadoop Fs use LITTLE_ENDIAN ?  because i can not make the other application use BIG_ENDIAN .

Comment: I believe it is not possible: https://books.google.com/books?id=Wu_xeGdU4G8C&lpg=PA94&ots=i8zSWFOdTu&dq=%22hadoop%22%20%22big%20endian%22&pg=PA94#v=onepage&q&f=false
"The bytes are written in big endian order which is dicated by the java.io.DataOutput interface". You cannot substitute DataOutput implementation as Hadoop uses FSDataOutputStream across the framework. You probably cannot monkey-patch in your job jar either, as other parts of the frameworks will still use the original one. You would have to patch the entire distribution.

Comment: If you absolutely can't use big-endian in nio, perhaps more promising approach would be transcode your data into big-endian in your mapper, then use it in the m/r flow, and then if necessary transcode the final output back to little-endian.